# BizTalk Mapping Single and Multiple elements

Tags: xslt-1.0, biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-2013r2

I am trying to transform via the map a single birth name node and multiple surname nodes into a repeating other surname nodes.  I'm running into some difficulties that when the birth name node is not present then multiple surname nodes fail to be written.

I've attempted multiple implementations around functoids and xslt call template neither appear to be working, as soon as the birth name is missing no surname elements are output.

Can this be done in functoids from the map ? or does this have to be done via a xslt call template?

### Schema Input

```
<root>
  <Subject>
    <birthname>
      <name>Birthname</name>
    </birthname>
    <multiplesurname>
      <name>surname</name>
    </multiplesurname>
    <multiplesurname>
      <name>surname2</name>
    </multiplesurname>
    <multiplesurname>
      <name>surname3</name>
    </multiplesurname>
  </Subject>
  <Mother></Mother>
  <Farther></Farther>
  <Other></Other>
</root>
```

### Schema Output

```
<root>
  <persona>
    <Othername>Birthname</Othername>
    <Othername>surname</Othername>
    <Othername>surname2</Othername>
    <Othername>surname3</Othername>
  </persona>
  <personb></personb>
</root>
```

Comment: Consider including what you've tried, whether with custom XSLT or a screen grab of the mapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running into further difficulties with XSLT call-template I found that a solution using functoids was possible and achieved using a combination of looping functoids from the birthname and multiplesurname along with straight link from the source node to the destination node.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problems may be caused by having a name node and then an descendant node also named name.  This might be causing an infinite loop for you.  Here is some XSLT code that will get the job done for you.

```
  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//name" mode="secondName"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name" mode="secondName">
    <xsl:element name="Othername">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

   <!-- Identity. -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I was adding an example snippet of the schema as the schema is very large.

Comment: Please see previous comment I revised with a XSLT solution.

Comment: @Bluewood66 - I think what he's getting at is that he'd need a lot more custom XSLT to do this in BizTalk.  BizTalk has OOB visual mapping functionality that can be supplemented with additional XSLT; it'd be more helpful to come up with a call template he could use.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with a table looper, but a XSLT call template for it shouldn't be too bad - something like this should work for you:

```
<xsl:template name="nameFlattener">
    <xsl:param name="birthname"/>
    <xsl:element name="Othername">
        <xsl:value-of select="$birthname"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:for-each select="//multiplesurname">
        <xsl:element name="Othername">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Have your `name` node from `birthname` going into that template as the first parameter, and output it to the `Othername` repeating node on the destination.

Comment: Thanks, still having difficulties with mapping multiplesurname seems to onlyy map birthname.  I had to add //Subject/multiplesurname to stop it adding every name in the other parent nodes (Mother, Farther, Other).